# What does (this:ClassName) parameter mean in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, parameters, abstract-class

I am a newbie to TypeScript.
I was confused what (this:ClassName) parameter of a function mean in an abstract class.
For example:

```
abstract class Department{
   abstract describe(this:Department):void;
}

class ITDepartment extends Department{
    describe(){
        console.log('IT Department');
    }
}
```

As above, the implementing child class does not have any parameter for describe() method, but the parent class has the parameter of (this:Department). What is this code telling me and why does this code work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO.

In TypeScript, if you've after a variable or parameter declaration a colon its defining the type of the given variable.
In your case you're declaring the `this` variable as type `Department`.
Normally you don't do this with class member functions, because the type of `this` is already known as the type of the class.